# ExtJs4 HTML Editor with images support

Tags: extjs, extjs4, wysiwyg, html-editor

I have a big web application written using ExtJs 4.0 framework. I need to add HTML WYSWYG editor with support for `<img>` tag and image upload (which built-in ExtJs HTML editor doesn't have).

I looked at TinyMCE, CKEditor and couple others but not sure which would be easier to integrate into existing ExtJs application.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I know there were at least two attempts at TinyMCE integration: [this one](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?143190-Ext.ux.TinyMCE-adaption-for-Ext4) and [that one](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?198699-Ext.ux.form.TinyMCETextArea-a-text-area-with-integrated-TinyMCE-WYSIWYG-Editor). I think I've seen CKEditor extension too.

You can also take a look at [Sencha Market](https://market.sencha.com).